# Microsoft Arc touch middle button

Tags: mouse, configuration, hardware

I got a Microsoft Arc Touch which I am able to connect and use on Ubuntu, however there seems to be no way to press the middle button (I tried double tapping the middle area and triple finger tapping and it didn’t work).

Searching the web, it is recommended to download the [Mouse and Keyboard Center](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/mouse-and-keyboard-center-download-f5b10905-7887-eedb-2f1c-d0737a36a3b2) from Microsoft to configure the middle button on Windows. Is there a similar way to configure the mouse on Ubuntu?

Comment: Based on [the lack of responses on Microsoft’s forum](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mobiledevices/forum/all/microsoft-arc-mouse-support-on-ubuntu/e80ea0ba-e3d0-47dc-bbcb-f057009e8408) and a similar pattern on various sites across the web, it may not be something that Microsoft is paying attention to, despite claiming to back Linux 

Comment: Yeah, I don't trust Microsoft to support linux. But I've always been able to find tools to hack my way around their devices. This mouse might be the one to stump me.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late, but just so you're aware, you only need to enable the middle-click configuration once, afterwards it should work on Ubuntu, macOS, or Android/iOS even (as any Bluetooth mouse). Maybe borrow someone's Windows laptop or use a public library?